# Unreal Engine keeps running the old Python file, even after bug fixes were made to that file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, unreal-engine5

please tell me what to do if Unreal Engine keeps running an old Python file, even after fixes have been made to that file.

I saw on youtube that someone uses the reload(filename) command in the console, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.